# Multiple post-fix expressions for an in-fix expression

Tags: stacks

Today I was learning to convert post-fix expressions to in-fix expressions and vice versa. What I want to know is **whether a post-fix expression can have more than one infix representations**.

For example, if I consider the following in-fix expression:

```
A+B-D/X
```

I get these post-fix expressions:

```
ABDX/-+
```

and

```
AB+DX/-
```

I didn't use the stack table method for solving these. I did these conceptually and both these expressions evaluate to

```
A+B-D/X
```

post-fix expression. I even verified my result with this [site](http://scanftree.com/Data_Structure/prefix-postfix-infix-online-converter) and both the post-fix expressions evaluate to:

```
A+B-D/X
```

Comment: Are you aware of operator precedence and operator associativity?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of these stuff:-)

Comment: Every expression, whether infix or postfix, has a unique parse tree. The two parse trees should match for the two expressions to be considered the same.

Comment: Also known as syntax trees. See for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Derivations_and_syntax_trees). This is a basic concept in context-free languages, which you might want to brush up on.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thank you very much for telling me. I finally fully understand it :)

Answer (score 1):

(A+b)-c and a+(b-c) are not the same. Not with integers (one expression might overflow while the other one doesn’t), not with floating-point numbers ( different rounding errors).

Only the second postfix expression is correct.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments by this [user](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/683/yuval-filmus), under the standard rules of operator precedence and operator associativity every expression has a unique expression tree representation. Now every ordered tree (including expression tree) results into unique sequences while traversing the tree in inorder or in preorder or in postorder. Now the inorder traversal of the expression tree gives us the infix expresion similarly postorder traversal gives the postfix expression.

Because of the one-to-one correspondence between a expression and its expression tree under the perview of operator precedence and operator associativity, you *cannot get more than one infix expression for a postfix exppression*. But you can always have two expressions which are equivalent in the sence that they evaluate to same result but they are not considered equal. `(10 + 20) + 30` and `10 + (20 + 30)` are equivalent but not same and have two different postfix expressions namely `10 20 + 30 +` and `10 20 30 + +`. Also, under the standard rules of operator precedence and operator associativity `10 + 20 + 30` corresponds to `(10 + 20) + 30`.